# How to get the latest data group by the category where type 0 must not display

Tags: google-sheets

Based on the data below, I would like to get the latest date for each category where the type must not be "0"

[image]

Here is the result that I would like to show
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these things to be true:

1. That your dates are actual dates that Google Sheets recognizes
2. That your dates are chronologically entered (i.e., a cell's date is always earlier than all the dates below it)

Use this formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(A:A),QUERY(IF(C:C<>0,A:C,""),"Select * Order by Col2 Desc"),{1, 2, 3},FALSE),""))`

How it works:

Working from the inside out...

`IF(C:C<>0,A:C,"")`

First create a limited range of only those rows in A:C that don't have a zero value as "TYPE" (Column C).

`QUERY(___,"Select * Order by Col2 Desc")`

QUERY this range in reverse (now all "most recent dates" will be at the top.

`VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(A:A),___,"Select * Order by Col2 Desc"),{1, 2, 3},FALSE)`

Look up each unique value in A:A (in your example, there are only 4: A, B, C and null). Use the upsidedown QUERY we created as the search range. Return the array formed of all three columns ({1, 2, 3}, in other words, all data per matching row). The categories are not guaranteed in any order, so we use FALSE at the end.

Since VLOOKUP stops when it finds a match, and the QUERY range is upside-down, the first match will always be the one with the most recent date.

`IFERROR(___,"")`

If there is no match (which will only happen with the UNIQUE value null), leave that final row in the array null as well.